# Installing Jasmine failing

Tags: html, jasmine

I'm trying to get Jasmine to work on my website. This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.1.3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/jasmine.css" />
<script src="/Scripts/UnitTesting/boot.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/UnitTesting/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/UnitTesting/jasmine.js"></script>
<!-- include source files here... -->

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="/Scripts/UnitTesting/HelloWorldSpec.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And HelloWorldSpec.js:

```
function helloWorld() {
    return "Hello world!";
}

describe("Hello world", function () {
    it("says hello", function () {
        expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

When I load this page, I get:

```
ReferenceError: jasmineRequire is not defined
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

I thought I got the reference to the JS files wrong. But when I look at the page source, and click on one of the js links, for example, "/Scripts/UnitTesting/boot.js", I see the source code, so it appears the files are loaded succesfully. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boot.js` file should be loaded after `jasmine.js` and `jasmine-html.js` Otherwise what would it boot? The correct order that you should include the files is:

1. `jasmine.js`
2. `jasmine-html.js`
3. `boot.js`

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/boot.html

> Starting with version 2.0, this file “boots” Jasmine, performing all of the necessary initialization before executing the loaded environment and all of a project’s specs. **This file should be loaded after jasmine.js and jasmine_html.js, but before any project source files or spec files are loaded.** Thus this file can also be used to customize Jasmine for a project.

Comment: Thanks, but I switched it around and the problem persists.

Comment: How about putting jasmine-html.js after jasmine.js as well? So that the order is: jasmine.js, jasmine-html.js, boot.js, your test specs.

Comment: That fixed it! In my own projects, I never need to worry about what order the files are in, so this completely went by me. Thanks for the help! I also put the correct order of the files in your answer, in case someone else finds this problem through Google.